# bodyParser not executing verify option in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, body-parser

I'm using body-parser for parsing the data in Sails.js. But is not executing verify option inside `bodyParser.json()`.

Here is my middleware configuration in *config/http.js* file:

```js
module.exports.http = {
 middleware: {

    order: [
      "cookieParser",
      "session",
      "bodyParser",
      "fileMiddleware",
      "router",
      "www",
      "favicon",
    ],

    bodyParser: (function () {
      const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
      console.log("body-parser executing");
      bodyParser.json({
        limit: "50MB",
        // for verifyingShopifyWebhook
        verify: function(req, res, buf, encoding) {
          console.log("buf", buf); //not getting printed on console
          if (req.url.search("/shopify/webhooks") >= 0) {
              console.log("inside bodyParser verify");
              req.rawbody = buf;
          }
        }
      });
      bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50MB", parameterLimit: 100000, extended:true });
      return bodyParser();
    })(),

    fileMiddleware: (function (){
      const multer = require("multer");
      const upload = multer();
      return upload.fields([{ name: "tagsFile", maxCount: 1 }]);
    })(),
  },
};
```

I'm getting `req.rawbody` as **undefined** when trying to access it in the controller function, and it is not even printing the `buf` object, so it seems like it is not calling the verify function at all.

Also, as middleware needs to be called on every request, then why App is just printing the `body-parser executing` at launching time and not on every request call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so finally I have found the answer after referring to the [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/blob/master/lib/skipper.js) code.

Here is what I did with my body-parser middleware:

```js
bodyParser: (function () {
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const JSONBodyParser = bodyParser.json({
      limit: "50MB",
      // for verifyingShopifyWebhook
      verify: function(req, res, buf, encoding) {
        if (req.url.search("/shopify/webhooks") >= 0) {
            console.log("inside bodyParser verify");
            req.rawbody = buf;
        }
      }
    });
    const URLEncodedBodyParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50MB", parameterLimit: 100000, extended:true });

    return function(req, res, next){
      if(req.is("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")){
        return URLEncodedBodyParser(req, res, next);
      } else {
        return JSONBodyParser(req, res, next);
      }
    }
})()
```

So rather than returning the `bodyParser()`, we need to return the particular parser.

Here, if the type is **x-www-form-urlencoded** then it will return `URLEncodedBodyParser`, otherwise it will return `JSONBodyParser`.